# Boxing bag capable of withstanding being outside 24/7

Tags: mixed-martial-arts, self-training, equipment

I am looking for a boxing bag to practice ground 'n pound, and ground game in general outside (small apartment).

I was thinking about a leather one, but I heard that leather might crack in the cold. Is that true? If so, what is a better alternative?

Comment: How will a boxing bag help with a ground game?

Comment: @mattm https://youtu.be/7lG0Rldh-2A?t=21 you can punch the bag, practice positions, transitions, and work on your ground striking.

Comment: You will freak everyone out if you start going wild on a bag on the ground in front of your apartment complex. It's just not the right place for that. I would avoid acting "violently" anywhere in public. And I wouldn't do it in an apartment, either (noise complaints). My only recommendation is to find a gym that has a private room to practice in, and allows you to bring and store your own equipment. Or join an MMA gym if possible, because they already have everything you need.

Comment: I am renting a part of a house with a garden. Sorry, English is my 2nd language. I will be training in the garden, and have a way to shield the bag from rain, snow and sunlight. I just want to know what material would be best to withstand the temp differences (from -20C to +30C). Also the gyms here will close soon (covid), hence the question.I also have mats to put under the bag so that it's not laying on the ground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many high-end/commercial bags now use ripstop (reinforced), UV resistant, crack resistant PVC.

I won't advertise any particular brands here, but an internet search for 'Ripstop boxing bags' will yield a range of useful results.

This material, combined with a sensible storage regimen, such as wrapping it in a tarpaulin and/or blankets when not in use (if outdoor storage is necessary), will likely serve you well for a long time.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Modern boxing bags can be made of synthetic fabric so they can withstand outside environments. I won't get into specific brands, but a "Makiwara" or outdoor rope lined punching board is also way cheaper and more disposable than a punching bag.

Comment: Mikawara would work for stand up. But I want to practice transitions and ground 'n pound. But thanks for the fabric tip!

Answer (score 0):

The other answers do a good job with material suggestions; I'll answer the other question: ***Will leather crack in the cold?***

The answer is that it depends on how often you use the bag and how well you keep it conditioned.  I had a leather bag that I kept outside through all seasons (including many, many days of freezing weather) and it was fine.  But I trained with it 6 days per week.  I also wiped my sweat off of it when I was done (they will mold if you do not).  I also kept it properly conditioned with oils.

On the other hand, I've seen neglected leather training bags that don't even make it through a few weeks in freezing temperatures.  Lack of use, excessive moisture or dryness, and lack of conditioners are usually to blame.

Leather bags like to be used frequently and dried off after each use.  When humidity is extremely low, they require more conditioners; when humidity is high, they usually don't require any conditioners, but do require steady airflow and more room to breathe and dry off.